# Assign Equality to Elements Directly out of Array Java

Tags: java

In python if you have a tuple or list of the form, `myTuple = (a,b,c)`, you can assign equality to different variables by saying `var1, var2, var3 = myTuple`. I was wondering if there was any way to do an analogous thing in Java.

Comment: No, you need to do it explicitly. E.g. a=array[0], b=array[1], c=array[2] etc.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Currently not possible I guess, I have seen this features only in dynamic programming languages like `Python` and `JavaScipt`. In `JS` you can do this `const [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: By the way, "assign equality" makes no sense.  What you are talking about is simply assigning or assignment.  The python feature is called "tuple assignment" ... and there is no equivalent language feature in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java , you cannot assign different variables values simultaneaously like this

`var1, var2, var3 = myTuple.`

You will have to do somthing like this :

```
int val[] = {1,2,3,4};
            int a,b,c,d=0;
        
                a = val[0];
                b = val[1];
                c = val[2];
                d = val[3];
```